# HOW to delay loading of images in uicollectionview using objective c

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

In my `UICollectionView` i am showing images i want to show the images one after another but its coming all at a time though i have used `dispatch_after` but its not working

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView  *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
            UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView    dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *showcardCollectionImageView;
         showcardCollectionImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 1, cell.frame.size.width - 2, cell.frame.size.height - 2)];
             dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 *  NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSString *cardImageString = [cardsimagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    showcardCollectionImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",cardImageString]];
    showcardCollectionImageView.hidden = NO;

    [cell addSubview:showcardCollectionImageView];
});


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: here to delay the images i have added dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()
but it s not working all the images coming delay
i want one after another

Comment: Please update the question and specify what are you doing , what issues you are facing and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you format this properly? It's very difficult to read "as is."

Comment: Your question is not clearly

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage, it's fast downloading image from server.

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

[imgOffer sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:objRecord.imgPath]
            placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]
                     options:0]
```